# N-Queens 2 leetcode question different output

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, n-queens

The n-queens puzzle is the problem of placing n queens on an n x n chessboard such that no two queens attack each other.

Given an integer n, return the number of distinct solutions to the n-queens puzzle.

This is my code for the n queens question. I cant find any error but my output keeps coming out to be 0. pls help

```
class Solution 
{
    public int totalNQueens(int n)
 {
        List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<>();
        function(n,0,result,new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return result.size();
    }
    
    
  public void function(int n, int row,List<List<Integer>> result,List<Integer> col)
    {
        if(n==row)
        {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(col));
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                col.add(i);
                if(isvalid(col))
                {
                 function(n,row+1,result,col);
                }
                else
                    col.remove(col.size()-1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public boolean isvalid(List<Integer> col)
    {
        // if(col.size()==1)
        //     return true;
        // int c=col.get(col.size()-1);
        int r=col.size()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            if(col.get(r)==col.get(i) || Math.abs(i-r)==Math.abs(col.get(r)-col.get(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting. It helps with reading your code.

Comment: You should step through it for the smallest case that has wrong output. Arrays seem a more natural representation of a board.

Comment: Your solution should remove each col entry after your recursive call to "function" (which could be more descriptively named) to check child paths whether it succeeds or not.  Otherwise, your first valid placement prevents all other possible placements for that row.